# Python: ValueError too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, машинное-обучение

Пытаюсь подобрать наилучшие параметры для модели с помощью GridSearchCV и как кросс валидацию хочу использовать данные за апрель. Код:

```
x_train.head()
```

[image: x_train.head()]

```
y_train.head()
```

[image: y_train.head()]

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
import xgboost as xg

xgb_parameters={'max_depth':[3,5,7,9],'min_child_weight':[1,3,5]}
xgb=xg.XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.1, n_estimators=100,max_depth=5, min_child_weight=1, gamma=0, subsample=0.8, colsample_bytree=0.8)
model=GridSearchCV(n_jobs=2,estimator=xgb,param_grid=xgb_parameters,cv=train_test_split(x_train,y_train,test_size=len(y_train['2016-04':'2016-04']), random_state=42, shuffle=False),scoring=my_func)
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
model.grid_scores_
model.best_params_
```

Когда запускаю код, возникает такая ошибка:
[image: Ошибка]

Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать в чем может быть дело? Спасибо

Comment: Вы можете пояснить что вы имеете ввиду под: `"как кросс валидацию хочу использовать данные за апрель"`? Обычно так не деалают...

Comment: @MaxU у меня есть данные с ноября по апрель. Я хочу на данных с ноября по март обучить модель, а на апреле измерить ее качество. И в дальнейшем использовать модель с наименьшей ошибкой. Наверное вы правы и понятие "кросс валидация" тут не совсем уместно. Более точно - измерить качество модели на отложенной выборке

Comment: Тогда просто разбейте набор данных на тренировочный (с ноября по март) и тестовый (апрель) и "скормите" тренировочные данные `GridSearchCV`. При обучении модель не должна видеть тестовые данные, иначе получите [`data leakage` (утечку данных)](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/)...

Comment: @MaxU  тогда не совсем понятно на каких данных GridSearchCV будет измерять качество моделей? Я хотел измерять качество на апреле, потому что в дальнейшем я делаю предсказания для мая и июня

Comment: дополнил ответ - надеюсь так стало понятнее как работает кросс-валидация в `GridSearchCV`...

Comment: @MaxU я понимаю как работает  GridSearchCV, только вот для прогнозирования временных рядов критично, чтобы данные располагались в хронологическом порядке. А если в cv передать просто какое то число, то данные будут перемешаны. Знаю, что еще можно передать в cv  TimeSeriesSplit, но там, к сожалению, нельзя указать размер выборки, на котором будет оцениваться качество модели

Comment: Может стоит преобразовать индекс (time stamp) в дополнительный признак (например в UNIX epoch- целое число)

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно указали параметр `cv` в вызове `GridSearchCV()`.

Вот что можно указывать в качестве `cv`:

```
cv : int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, optional
    Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy.
    Possible inputs for cv are:
      - None, to use the default 3-fold cross validation,
      - integer, to specify the number of folds in a `(Stratified)KFold`,
      - An object to be used as a cross-validation generator.
      - An iterable yielding train, test splits.

    For integer/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and ``y`` is
    either binary or multiclass, :class:`StratifiedKFold` is used. In all
    other cases, :class:`KFold` is used.

    Refer :ref:`User Guide <cross_validation>` for the various
    cross-validation strategies that can be used here.
```

`train_test_split` возвращает четыре массива: `X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train`, `y_test`, это и вызывает указанную ошибку.

В вашем случае достаточно указать `cv=3` (или другое целое число "folds" для кросс-валидации).

Если указать целое число (например 3), то `GridSearchCV()` подготовит три случайных разбивки (splits) на тренировочный и тестовые наборы данных. В каждом случае размер тренировочной выборки будет равен приблизительно `2/3` и тестовой `1/3` для `cv=3` (для `cv=5` это будет соотвественно `4/5` и `1/5`). Все эти разбивки учавствуют в подборе гиперпараметров.

Пример:

если указать `cv=3` и `xgb_parameters={'max_depth':[3,5,7,9],'min_child_weight':[1,3,5]}`, то у `GridSearchCV()` всего будет:

```
4 (max_depth) * 3 (min_child_weight) * 3 (cv) = 36
```

задач.

PS при обучении модели убедитесь, что модель при обучении не видит тестовых данных, чтобы избежать [`data leakage`](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/).